# Is it possible to search with regular expression in "Intellij Search Everywhere"?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, search

In Eclipse there is a feature which is called "Open Type in Hierarchy". We use the shortcut: `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `H` on Windows or  `Cmd` + `Shift` + `H`  on Mac. It provides special characters (*, ?, etc.). So you can list Java types with specific pattern.

[Open Type in Hierarchy in Eclipse (Screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdOlu.png)

When I tried to list all classes in IntelliJ, I wasn't able to get the same result. Probably IntelliJ doesn't understand this "*" character.

[Search Everywhere in IntelliJ (Screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSIMi.png)

Is there any kind of search mechanism in IntelliJ to get the same result?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I think "*" doesn't work because Intellij evaluates mathematical expressions using it(from search everywhere). You could try one of the search methods defined in [IntelliJ: Search everywhere](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/searching-everywhere.html) for you query.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `ctrl`+`shift`+`f` (to find in files) you can hit `alt`+`x` to enable regex searching. It's got all kinds of useful stuff.

`ctrl`+`n` (the class search) also understands '*', but not regex.

`ctrl`+`h` will show a hierarchy, but I'm not aware of a filter mechanism that might help there.

You can find other useful shortcuts here (and their Mac equivalents): https://resources.jetbrains.com/storage/products/intellij-idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf

In you first screenshot you seem to be searching a jar; in the 2nd you're actually searching 'in all places'. If you click on that dropdown you can restrict where you're searching. The filtering button might also be helpful.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Joe. But 'ctrl+shift+f' doesn't help me. Because I just want to list java types like in eclipse. Also I didn't find this short cut 'ctrl+n' in this page : https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Keymaps_Comparison_Windows.html (I'm using mac so the key map is different from windows.)

Comment: On a mac its apple+o. Maybe you'll find what you're looking for here: https://resources.jetbrains.com/storage/products/intellij-idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf. I updated the Answer as well.

Comment: In my question, there are two screen shots. the second one is the screen shot for this. Unfortunately it didn't work. -> Search Everywhere in IntelliJ (Screenshot)