# How to search for a regex everywhere in IntelliJ or Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

In Android Studio (IntelliJ), I know how to:

1. Search **everywhere** for a [string](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/guide/tips/search-everywhere/#:%7E:text=Use%20%E2%87%A7%E2%87%A7%20(macOS)%2C,area%2C%20such%20as%20%2Feditor.) (not necessarily a symbol, could be in a comment).
2. Search **in a file** for a [regex](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/tutorial-finding-and-replacing-text-using-regular-expressions.html) (not necessarily a symbol, could be in a comment)
3. Search **everywhere** for a "regexed" [symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70724290/is-it-possible-to-search-with-regular-expression-in-intellij-search-everywhere).

But I have not been able to find a way to search for a **non-symbol**, **regex**, **everywhere**, style [AstroGrep](https://astrogrep.sourceforge.net/).

Is this at all possible in Android Studio version 2021.3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the menu item `Edit | Find | Find in Files` <kbd>Ctrl/Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>. In the dialog that appears you can enable regex search with the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> or use the mouse.

(At least that is how it works in IntelliJ IDEA. I assume it works the same in Android Studio)

Comment: Thank you. This works beautifully in Android Studio version 2021.3. I wonder why the `Alt`+`X` thing doesn't work when "Find in Files" is invoked via "double-`Shift`".

Comment: I would also add that a convenient shortcut to `Edit | Find | Find in Files` is `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`F`.